# Why doesn't my scope show with a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm creating a directive with a custom controller and testing out the scope. I want to test if the directive has a scope from my index page but the ng-show is not working.

html

```
<div class="main">
<div ng-controller="rl">

<book-genres></book-genres>
<review-form ng-show="reviewFormCtrl.rating == 1"></review-form>
<input ng-click="reviewFormCtrl.rating = 3" type="button" value="Test" /> 

</div>

</div>
```

partial:

```
<div>
    Review Forms : {{ rating }}

</div>
```

controller:

```
myApp.controller('rl', function(){

});

myApp.directive('reviewForm',  function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'partials/review-form.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        controller: function($scope){
                $scope.rating = 1;
        },
        controllerAs: 'reviewFormCtrl'
    };
});
```

Comment: why is `<div ng-controller="rl">` and then `reviewFormCtrl.rating` ? Did you alias it ?

Comment: rl is just a blank controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using the controller as syntax (e.g. `controllerAs: 'reviewFormCtrl'`), you should attach rating to the controller instead of scope.

This should work

```
myApp.directive('reviewForm',  function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'partials/review-form.html',
    replace: true,
    scope: true,
    controller: function(){
      this.rating = 1;  //change here
    },
    controllerAs: 'reviewFormCtrl'
  };
});
```

Comment: that worked.  I also had to had  <div>
    Review Forms : {{ reviewFormCtrl.rating }}
</div>

Comment: Sorry, I missed the problem with the partial.  Just remember that all `controller as reviewFormCtrl` is provide a reference to the controller on the $scope using the key reviewFormCtrl.  Basically somewhere in angular code this happens with controller as: `$scope.reviewFormCtrl = <your controller>`.  You could have solved this same problem with fewer changes by changing ng-show in your html file to `ng-show="rating == 1"`

Answer (score 0):

As @Dustin Hodges said but I suggest you a cleaner way

**Directive:**

```
angular
 .module('myApp')
 .directive('reviewForm',  function(){

  var directive = {
      restrict    : 'E',
      templateUrl : 'partials/review-form.html',
      replace     : true,
      scope       : true,
      controller  : 'ReviewFormController'
      controllerAs: 'reviewformCtrl'
  };

 return directive;

});
```

**Controller:**

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller('ReviewFormController', ReviewFormController);

  ReviewFormController.$inject = [];//your dependencies

  function ReviewFormController(){

    var vm = this;

    vm.rating = 1;

  }
```

**Template:**

```
<div class="main">
 <book-genres></book-genres>
  <review-form ng-show="reviewformCtrl.rating == 1"></review-form>
</div>
```

Hope I've been helpful.

Comment: If I add a ng-click to change the rating, will this work?   <input ng-click="reviewFormCtrl.rating = 9" type="button" value="Test" /> It should hide the review-form but nothing's happening.

Comment: Note that the `controllerAs` is `reviewformCtrl` not `reviewFormCtrl`.

Comment: I made some updates. The ng-click is not working still.